# how and where to initialize jquery datatable in backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, backbone.js, datatable, backbone-views

My html template look like this:

```
   <script type="text/template" id="players-template">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>group</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="playersTable"></tbody>
        </table>
    </script>  


    <script type="text/template" id="player-list-item-template">
        <td><@= name @></td>
        <td>
            <@ _.each(hroups, function(group) { @>
            <@= group.role @>
            <@ }); @>
        </td>            
    </script>
```

My backbone view is as follows:

```
   playerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template( $("#player-template").html() ),
    initialize: function () 
        if(this.collection){
            this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html( this.template );
        this.collection.each(function(player) {
            var itemView = new app.PlayerListItemView({ model: player });
            itemView.render();
            this.$el.find('#playersTable').append(itemView.$el);
        },this

 });

 // view to  generate each player for list of players
PlayerListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
   template: _.template($('#player-list-item-template').html()),
       tagName: "tr",
      render: function (eventName) {
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
         }
  });
```

The above code works perfectly. Now, I want to use apply jquery datatable plugin wtih bootstrap support. You can find detail here :http://www.datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2 
So, I just added the line inside render as:

```
        render: function () {
        this.$el.html( this.template );
        this.collection.each(function(player) {
                var itemView = new app.PlayerListItemView({ model: player });
               itemView.render();
              this.$el.find('#playersTable').append(itemView.$el);
              $('#example').dataTable( {
                console.log('datatable');
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i>   <'span6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                  { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 2 ] }
               ]
            } );
        },this);

    },
```

Now, the jquery datable is not initialized. They just diisplay normal table.

- where should I intialized the table to apply jquery datatable?
- they worked perfectly without backbone.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, the jQuery plugin needs the elements to be on the page to work.  You don't show where you are calling `render` on that view, but I am going to assume you are doing something like this:

```
var view = new PlayerView();
$('#foo').html(view.render().el);  // this renders, then adds to page
```

If this is true, then using the plugin inside render is too early, since the view's html is not yet added to the page.

You can try this:

```
var view = new PlayerView();
$('#foo').html(view.el);   // add the view to page before rendering
view.render();
```

Or you can try this:

```
var view = new PlayerView();
$('#foo').html(view.render().el);
view.setupDataTable();    // setup the jQuery plugin after rendering and adding to page
```

Comment: In `render`, if you write `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))`, is it possible to then call `this.setupDataTable()` so long as when you instantiate the datatable you write `this.$('#tableId').DataTable(..)`? That way the jQuery selector is scoped to the view's `$el`. EDIT: I tried this and received an error about a missing `aDataSort`.